# Nexus NPM Repository

Tags: jenkins, npm, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, nexus

Is it possible to upload ".zip" file in NPM type Nexus Repository ?

nexusArtifactUploader artifacts: [[artifactId: 'spring-petclinic', classifier: '', file: 'target/9.0.0-rc1.zip', type: 'zip']], credentialsId: 'ff154118-e8d1-4c40-a63b-5ce5821c347c', groupId: 'Pet_Clinic', nexusUrl: 'uat.alm.com/nexus', nexusVersion: 'nexus3', protocol: 'https', repository: 'NexusTest1_Release', version: '1.0.0.0'

Getting this error :
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking at : https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/nexus-artifact-uploader/ it looks like you can. I think you just need to add `'type:'zip'`

if you need an exemple my own pipeline, using nexusArtifactuploader (for tgz archive) :

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'nexusId', usernameVariable: 'nexusUser', passwordVariable: 'nexusPwd')]) {
    nexusArtifactUploader(
        nexusVersion: 'nexus3',
        protocol: 'https',
        nexusUrl: 'myNexusUrl',
        groupId: 'mygroupId',
        version: tagG,
        repository: 'myRepo',
        credentialsId: 'nexusId',
        artifacts: [
            [artifactId: 'myArchive',
            type:'tgz',
            classifier: '',
            file: "myArchive-${tagG}.tgz"]
        ]
    )
}
```